# Return All Days Based off Date Range

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following simple query. What I'm needing to do is show the count(*) of that query result for every day based on a date-range.

For example, if a daterange of @StartDate = '01 Jul 2019' and an @EndDate of '01 Feb 2020' is chosen, the query would need to show the result for every-day from '01 Jul 2019' to '01 Feb 2020'. I could only think of doing this with a While Loop, but ideally I need the query as a view.

Any ideas?

```
select count(*) from Data
where
    StartDate <= '31 July 2019' and 
    ([EndDate] >='31 July 2019' or [EndDate] is null)
```

I have put together this query also but it fails:

```
select 
    DD.Date,
    (
            select count(*) from Data
            where
                StartDate <= DD.Date and 
                ([EndDate] >=DD.Date or [EndDate] is null)
                and 
                Data.StartDate = DD.Date --not sure what to join on given the 2 date fields above
    ) as Count
from 
    DimDate DD
where 
Date >='2019-07-01' and Date <='2020-02-01'
```

Comment: A _numbers_ (aka _tally_) table is helpful.

Comment: @HABO - I do have a Date table with all available dates within it.

Comment: You ought to be able to `select` all of the dates between `@StartDate` and `@EndDate` from your `[Date]` table. For each row from `[Date]` you could retrieve the `count` from `Data` using a subquery.

Comment: Was the above what you were thinking @HABO? The join is what is confusing me

Comment: If you are after a count of days, what about using the datediff function?

Comment: Based on the DDL and sample data you provided, it might be that your `Data` table has a range of dates per row and that for each date in a specified range you want the count of `Data` rows that include the date. Shall we guess that a subquery like `select Count( 42 ) from Data as D where D.StartDate <= DD.[Date] and DD.Date <= Coalesce( D.EndDate, DD.Date )` will meet your vague needs? (If any of the "dates" include times then it gets a little more interesting.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work for you. It doesn't perform well with a lot of data, but I don't know how much data you have. I will see if I can refine it. Or maybe someone else can.

```
SELECT
            DD.dt
          , x.Count
FROM        DimDate DD
CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Count]
                FROM   Data
                WHERE  StartDate <= DD.dt
                       AND (
                               EndDate >= DD.dt
                               OR EndDate IS NULL
                           )
            )                   x
WHERE       DD.dt BETWEEN '2019-07-01' AND '2020-02-01'
```

This will work too (very close to what you had).

```
SELECT
            DD.dt
         ,  (
                SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Count]
                FROM   Data
                WHERE  StartDate <= DD.dt
                       AND (
                               EndDate >= DD.dt
                               OR EndDate IS NULL
                           )
            ) AS [Count]
FROM        DimDate DD
WHERE       DD.dt BETWEEN '2019-07-01' AND '2020-02-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

One line does it. It's the DateDiff function, which takes parameter dd for days and the start and end dates.

You can use other parameters found in the following website: 
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datediff.asp

```
 select DateDiff(dd, StartDate, EndDate)
```

select dateDiff(dd, cast('1/1/1991' as date) , cast('1/1/1990' as date)) will get you -365